# Datepicker not working when integrating in already existing document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to implement datepicker. When I use the code in the empty document it works, but when I try to implement in already existing documents it does not work.

Code in empty document:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I put links and scripts in head of the document and input field in the body. But nothing happens when I click input field. Any ideas?

Maybe there is something I should change in script declarations in header?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It dont seem like there is any problems at all with your code. I just ran your code and it works fine.

Comment: make sure you don't have any other element with the same ID

Comment: I have only 1 element with this id.There must be other elements that stop dapicker from displaying, but no idea which.

Comment: Have your checked if your get any errors in your Console log?

Hit F12 and check your Console and see if there is any errors.

Comment: Yes but there are no errors mentioning datepicker. Even if i delete it there are same errors.

Comment: What is the error? It may be related to JQuery, and if that is not loading, datepicker won't either.

Comment: This might also be a conflict in your JQuery Version vs your UI Version.